# Shortest one-line shell script to print all special characters

Tags: shell-script, special-characters

I'm looking for a **shortest one line shell script** to print all special characters in ASCII table ***(from chr(32) --> chr(127))***

Thanks for all your help & support!

Comment: Please define in your question what exactly means "all special characters". (If you have a file named `x` that contains "all special characters" you can print them with `cat x`. ;-) )

Comment: `man ascii` is pretty short

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
$ print -aC16 {' '..$'\177'}
   !  "  #  $  %  &  '  (  )  *  +  ,  -  .  /
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;  <  =  >  ?
@  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  [  \  ]  ^  _
`  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o
p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  {  |  }  ~  ^?
```

Or:

```
$ (){print -raC16 ${(#)@}} {32..127}
   !  "  #  $  %  &  '  (  )  *  +  ,  -  .  /
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;  <  =  >  ?
@  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  [  \  ]  ^  _
`  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o
p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  {  |  }  ~
```

(this time the DEL control character (chr(127)) is not transformed to `^?`, so you will probably not see it).